# How to check that email address isn't already in use when updating it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my website, I have allowed my users to update their email address. However, I require that each email address be unique. How can I ensure that the email address which is entered on the update form is unique before updating it in the database?

Comment: How did you ensure it was unique when they enter it the first time ?

Comment: I used the membershipcreatestatus.

Answer (score 1):

Have a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the column that stores your email address.

> You can use UNIQUE constraints to make sure that no duplicate values
>   are entered in specific columns that do not participate in a primary
>   key.

Blindly inserting in a table with unique constraints will throw an exception. To avoid this, run a select query checking for this email address in the where clause.

If you have a large user base, be sure to index your email column.

Comment: Is this possible for the default aspnet_Users table? I wouldn't want to mess that up...

Comment: @AndreC are you sure a unique constraint doesn't already exist?

Comment: I have it set so that the email should be unique, however, does this apply if I want to update the field? Or is it only for creating the field?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some key on the table, and your initial statement was:

```
UPDATE dbo.foo SET Email = @Email WHERE Key = @key;
```

Then you can check for values first:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.foo WHERE Email = @Email AND Key <> @Key)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Sorry, that e-mail is already in use.', 11, 1);
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  UPDATE dbo.foo SET Email = @Email WHERE Key = @key;
END
```

Now, you should have a constraint on the table anyway, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Email
 UNIQUE(Email);
```

But it can still be beneficial to check for violations first, even with a constraint in place, [as I demonstrated here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score -1):

My first recommendation would be defining this as a unique column in the table, [see this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp). Alternatively, and not in my opinion a very good way to do this (but maybe for some reason you don't control the tables) you could check this in your insert statement. If you can provide more information (table structure / insert statement) I will be able to provide a better answer for you.